# Prove the function $\displaystyle f(p)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^p}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is increasing in $p$.

Tags: inequality

The parameters $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: This follows from Holder's inequality.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain it more precisely? I have considered Hölder's inequality and I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!